# How ARP is allowed?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, mac-address, arp

I read on stack-overflow:

> MAC addresses and IP addresses operate on different layers of the
> internet protocol suite. MAC addresses are used to identify machines
> within the same broadcast network on layer 2, while IP addresses are
> used on layer 3 to identify machines throughout different networks.

But also read that devices on different networks don't know / shouldn't each other MAC address. But how this makes sense?

Before communicating devices send ARP request with the destination ip to know the MAC address.

Comment: `Before communicating devices send ARP request with the destination ip to know the MAC address.` Only for IPs in the local network.

Comment: MAC addresses are used by IEEE layer-2 protocols to deliver frames on the same layer-2 domain, but not all layer-2 protocols use MAC addressing. Packets are layer-3 datagrams that are the payload of layer-2 frames. Routers will strip off the layer-2 frame, losing any layer-2 information, and forward the layer-3 packet, building a new. different layer-2 frame for the next link in the path toward the destination network.

Answer (score 0):

> But also read that devices on different networks don't know / shouldn't each other MAC address. But how this makes sense?

MAC addresses are only valid/useful for nodes sharing a common data link layer segment (L2).

> Before communicating devices send ARP request with the destination ip to know the MAC address.

Only for a local destination IP (on the same subnet).

You need to send IP packets for remote destinations to your local gateway, so you'd use the gateway's MAC.